# Creating ActionScript Date object from MySQL UTC timestamp string

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3

I'm storing Date in `datetime` column of MySQL table. I'm inserting current date by calling [MySql's UTC_CURRENTDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp). When I retrieve it, it's in following string format:  `"2012-07-24 12:59:58"`

When I try to create a Date object in Action Script by doing the following:

```
var dateNum:Number = Date.parse(createDate); // this gives me NaN
var createDate:Date = new Date(dateNum);
```

`Date.parse("2012-07-24 12:59:58")` gives `NaN`

**Solution:** Following Jason's advice, I'm doing the following:

Select a [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)(CREATE_DATE) which returns me seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC.  Then do following in Actionscript:

```
var createDate:Date = new Date();
var offset:Number = createDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; 
createDate.time = parseInt("1343174921") * 1000 - offset;
```

This gives me the right date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm sure there's a more elegant approach; clearly you could implement a parse function such as:

```
public static function parse(date:String):Date
{
    var split:Array = date.split(" ");
    var splitDate:Array = split[0].split("-");
    var splitTime:Array = split[1].split(":");

    return new Date(splitDate[0],
                    splitDate[1] - 1,
                    splitDate[2],
                    splitTime[0],
                    splitTime[1],
                    splitTime[2]);
}
```

Called as:

```
var date:Date = parse("2012-07-24 12:59:58");
```

Instead of handling MySQL `DATETIME`, your SQL statements could convert to timestamps which ActionScript `Date` constructor would accept milliseconds since epoch.

Frameworks such as [CASA Lib](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_util_DateUtil.html) have nice date utility functions.

Comment: I kinda went in the direction you suggested by returning mysql's unix timestamp instead.  I updated my question with a solution. My one confusion is with time offset. Do I add or subtract it? How do I know which to do? In this case I did trial and error and got right time by subtracting.

Comment: Add minutes to the date from the user's `timezoneOffset` as in: `d.minutes += d.timezoneOffset;`  I'm GMT-0500, in which my offset is 300 minutes with daylight savings.  It's 2:55pm CDT and 7:55pm UTC.

Comment: Actually, you need the other direction - for UTC to local, subtract `timezoneOffset`.

Comment: Documentation http://tinyurl.com/capu3po says "this value is the number of minutes you need to add to the computer's local time to equal UTC. If your computer's time is set later than UTC, the value will be negative."  Is there an easy way to figure out if computer's time is set later/earlier than UTC?

Comment: I believe timezoneOffset is negative in that instance.  That's a great question in itself - translating AS3 `Date` from UTC to local time with milliseconds from epoch.