# Translating ActionScript Date from UTC to local time with milliseconds from epoch

Tags: actionscript-3

This is a follow up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632421/creating-actionscript-date-object-from-mysql-utc-timestamp-string). In my solution to get current time, I need to add/subtract offset:

```
var createDate:Date = new Date();
var offset:Number = createDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; 
createDate.time = parseInt("1343174921") * 1000 - offset; // subtracting offset
```

To get correct time, I had to subtract offset(pure guess).  How do I know to subtract or add offset? The documentation for [getTimezoneOffset](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#timezoneOffset) says:

> this value is the number of minutes you need to add to
>   the computer's local time to equal UTC. If your computer's time is set
>   later than UTC, the value will be negative.

Is there an easy way to figure out if computer's time is set later/earlier than UTC so that I know if I need to add or subtract offset?

**update** I've checked the database and I'm storing an entry that was created on `7/25/2012 at 8pm` as `1343282417` (I'm using [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) to store date). When I plug it into Unix timestamp converter I get `Thu, 26 Jul 2012 06:00:17 GMT`.  So I'm confused why does MySql's UTC_TIMESTAMP ( that suppose to return the current UTC date and time) gives me a different date. I'm working locally both the MySQL db, php and Flash code are on single machine.

Comment: Isn't getTimezoneOffset going to be positive or negative depending  on it is set earlier or later? So you should just use addition and if getTimezoneOffset returns negative it will be subtracted.

if(createDate.getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ) timeSetLater than UTC.

Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I'm in US Central time, so should getTimezoneOffset be negative?

Comment: It should be positive, I'm in Toronto so that EST I get 240 from getTimezoneOffset.

Comment: Then if I add that offset createDate.time = parseInt("1343174921") * 1000 + offset; (substitute the string in parseInt for your time).  I get wrong time. It's only when I subtract the offset, do I see the right time. I'm msising something here.

Comment: try not using int but instead use Number createDate.time = Number("1343174921") * 1000 + offset; INT can only get so big before your code breaks and you are *1000+offset which makes it very large

Comment: Used createDate.time = Number("1343174921") * 1000 + offset; gives me a wrong time again.

Comment: ok let me get this right. the number you posted 1343174921 is the seed time stamp of GMT so in other words it's offset to GMT is 0. Is that correct?

Comment: The number is what I get from MySQL statement  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CREATE_DATE)

Comment: Sorry for the questions but is CREATE_DATE the local time of the server?

Comment: It looks like that it's a problem with storing the right date. I updated question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty much your answer, isn't it?

> this value is the number of minutes you need to add to the computer's
>   local time to equal UTC. If your computer's time is set later than
>   UTC, the value will be negative.

Meaning that you need to always ADD `getTimezoneOffset` to the local Date to get the UTC Date

So,

```
var now:Date=new Date();

var utcOffset=now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

var utcNow:Date=new Date(now.valueOf() + utcOffset);
```

You now have the utc time in `utcNow`.

**Note:** `utcNow` is just a false representation of the utc time (it is the current UTC time in the user's timezone. That is, a `toString()` will have the user's original timezone appended. To get the UNIX timestamp, use `utcNow.valueOf()`

There are inbuilt API functions `getUTCDate`, `getUTCFullYear`, `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes`, `getUTCMilliseconds`, `getUTCMonth`, and `getUTCSeconds` which you can call on the original (`now`) Date object to get those values only.

Comment: That's what I thought but if I add the getTimezoneOffset I get a wrong time. I have to subtract it to get the right time.