# How do I convert a sql Date object to a usable object (String or otherwise) in Adobe flex

Tags: sql-server, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I am pulling a row from a sql database that may contain a Date object in one of its columns into an Adobe Air application. When the Date object is present, it is returned as an apparently unusable (cannot discern any date info from it) object.

[image: Variable view in Flash Builder]

How do I extract the date information from this object or is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think so no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating ActionScript Date object from MySQL UTC timestamp string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632421/creating-actionscript-date-object-from-mysql-utc-timestamp-string)